# Outlook 2010 Deleted Items

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, delay

I have a user that has a funny issue with Outlook.

The user is running windows 7 ent with office 2010.

The user has been trying to find an email that he had put into his deleted folder. 
When he opens the deleted items folder, there are no messages in there but in the bottom Left corner, it says that there are over 1000 items.

If the folder is kept open for 10 minutes the items will suddenly appear.

The user can access other peoples mailbox and has no problems access their deleted folders.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running `scanpst` on his `.pst` file?

Comment: Is the user connecting directly to exchange? If so, which version?

Comment: yes, Directly connected to exchange. We are using exchange 2010

Comment: Because all mailboxes aare connected to our exchange, we done use PST files.